# Black loading screen

Tags: boot, nvidia, xubuntu, screen

This is the first time that I use Xubuntu and I'm experiencing a problem with it. D:
I've just installed Xubuntu 12.10 desktop 64-bit on my laptop alongside with Windows 8.
When I choose Ubuntu from grub loader, the screen goes black and the LCD backlight goes off: the white-bar-on-blue-background Xubuntu loading screen doesn't appear, but after a few seconds the Xfce login window materializes and the desktop enviroment after login works fine. When I shutdown or restart the system, the white-bar-on-blue-background Xubuntu loading screen magically appears! :)
I know that is only an aesthetic bug, but how can I bring back the Xubuntu loading screen on boot?
Please notice that my video card is the Nvidia NVS 2100M, and that I'm NOT experiencing any problem with Xfce's desktop.
A huge kiss to anyone who will help me! :*

Comment: possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075/22949) (There are some answers there that give the same advice as [the upvoted answer here](http://askubuntu.com/a/254767/22949). The description of the problem is a bit different but it seems like it could be caused by some of the same factors discussed there, especially if the backlight is turning off. If you're still having this problem with a now-supported Ubuntu release, please let us know.)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be specific to particular graphics cards. It just appears that the framebuffer code or the choice when to use it is less robust on some newer Ubuntu versions. I am encountering the same on some of my machines. What you can do is on the `grub` prompt use `vbeinfo` and see which graphic modes are supported. Then after booting do

```
sudo editor /etc/default/grub
```

and uncomment the line `#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480`, i.e. remove the `#`. Then adjust the resolution to a value that was listed as supported by `grub` on the prompt.

After that run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and test by rebooting.

If you want to get rid of the progress screen and prefer the classic console output, simply don't edit the line mentioned above and instead uncomment the line `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`.