# How to recover nice Ubuntu boot screen?

Tags: boot

My computer starts normally, but I would like to recover nice Ubuntu boot screen. GRUB is also working perfectly and from the moment I select option "Ubuntu 13.04" (in the GRUB where all systems are listed) I cannot see boot screen... The character "_" blinks and after some time NVidia logo appears and system starts normally.

This is the first few lines from the log file:

```
May 24 20:17:01 xxx CRON[2682]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report 
/etc/cron.hourly)
May 24 20:17:21 xxx colord: device removed: xrandr-Seiko Epson Corporation  
May 24 20:17:21 xxx colord: Profile removed: icc-1a481a1e08438b83bedb96e72eb42d3a 
May 24 20:17:24 xxx gnome-session[1854]: CRITICAL: gsm_manager_set_phase: assertion `GSM_IS_MANAGER (manager)' failed 
May 24 20:17:24 xxx gnome-session[1854]: Gtk-CRITICAL: gtk_main_quit: assertion `main_loops != NULL' failed 
May 24 20:19:19 xxx kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started. 
May 24 20:19:19 xxx rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="931" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start 
May 24 20:19:19 xxx rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103 
May 24 20:19:19 xxx rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101 
May 24 20:19:19 xxx rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the boot messages, that question is answered here

[How can I show or hide boot messages when Ubuntu starts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this wil work but have you tried using boot-repair to restore grub to its default settings so to speak.

Have a look here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: that won't help. I even tried this http://askubuntu.com/questions/254761/black-loading-screen and it didn't help.

Comment: Maybe I have misunderstood exactly what is wrong here. Are you seeing the grub screen to select os

Comment: Yes, I can see GRUB screen to select os, and I can select os. But after that I have blank screen, but system starts normally.